# Fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, heroku

When I run git push heroku main, I'm getting this. To let you know that I this is my second project I'm trying to push to heroku. I already pushed a project following heroku document, it worked without any fatal. But this time I'm getting this fatal. I don't why I'm getting this

fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run `heroku login`

Answer (score 0):

The same started happening to me after they reset my password (due to that issue). Actually, in my local machine was still working but when I tried to deploy from my GitHub it showed me that message.
I had to update my API Key (in my case, updated it in my GitHub SECRETS section).
After this, things went back to normal.